# Sometimes no sound when turning the cards from front to back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
</head>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\card\flip-sound.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>






<main>
  <h1>TM</h1>
  <p>Game Cards.</p>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>
<ul>
  <li class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvels</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
  <iframe class="frame" 
  width="225"
  height="340"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
  title="YouTube video player"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
  allowfullscreen
></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>113.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
 
  
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <p class="card__name"><span>Aaron</span><br>Rodgers</p>
        <p class="card__num">12</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>112.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Ben</span><br>Roethlisberger</p>
        <p class="card__num">7</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>103.3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Peyton</span><br>Manning</p>
        <p class="card__num">18</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>101.5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Tom</span><br>Brady</p>
        <p class="card__num">Eric</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Drew</span><br>Brees</p>
        <p class="card__num">9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(48, 48, 48, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  animation: shine 2s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}



.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(52, 79, 148, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(53, 79, 148, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(53, 80, 149, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(54, 80, 150, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(54, 81, 150, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(55, 81, 151, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(55, 82, 152, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(55, 82, 152, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(56, 83, 153, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(56, 83, 154, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(57, 83, 154, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(57, 84, 155, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(57, 84, 156, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(58, 85, 156, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(58, 85, 157, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(59, 86, 157, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(59, 86, 158, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(59, 87, 159, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(60, 87, 159, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(60, 88, 160, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(61, 88, 160, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(61, 88, 161, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(61, 89, 162, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(62, 89, 162, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(62, 90, 163, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(62, 90, 163, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(63, 90, 164, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(63, 91, 164, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(63, 91, 165, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(64, 92, 165, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(64, 92, 166, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(64, 92, 166, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(65, 93, 167, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(65, 93, 167, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(65, 94, 168, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(66, 94, 169, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(66, 94, 169, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(66, 95, 170, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(67, 95, 170, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(67, 96, 171, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(67, 96, 171, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(68, 96, 171, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(68, 97, 172, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(68, 97, 172, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(69, 97, 173, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(69, 98, 173, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(69, 98, 174, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(69, 98, 174, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(70, 99, 175, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(70, 99, 175, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(70, 99, 176, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(71, 100, 176, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(71, 100, 177, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(71, 100, 177, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(71, 101, 177, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(72, 101, 178, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(72, 101, 178, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(72, 102, 179, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(73, 102, 179, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(73, 102, 180, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(73, 103, 180, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(73, 103, 180, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(74, 103, 181, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(74, 103, 181, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(74, 104, 182, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(74, 104, 182, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(75, 104, 182, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(75, 105, 183, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(75, 105, 183, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(75, 105, 184, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(76, 106, 184, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(76, 106, 184, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(76, 106, 185, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(76, 106, 185, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(77, 107, 185, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(77, 107, 186, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(77, 107, 186, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(77, 107, 187, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(77, 108, 187, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(78, 108, 187, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(78, 108, 188, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(78, 109, 188, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(78, 109, 188, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(79, 109, 189, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(79, 109, 189, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(79, 110, 189, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(79, 110, 190, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(80, 110, 190, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(80, 110, 190, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(81, 111, 192, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(81, 112, 192, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(81, 112, 192, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(81, 112, 193, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(81, 112, 193, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(82, 113, 193, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(82, 113, 194, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(34, 108, 42, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(35, 109, 43, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(35, 110, 43, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(35, 110, 43, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(35, 111, 44, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(36, 112, 44, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(36, 113, 44, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(36, 114, 45, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(36, 114, 45, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(37, 115, 45, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(37, 116, 46, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(37, 117, 46, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(37, 118, 46, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(38, 118, 47, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(38, 119, 47, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(38, 120, 47, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(38, 121, 47, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(39, 121, 48, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(39, 122, 48, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(39, 123, 48, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(39, 124, 49, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(40, 124, 49, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(40, 125, 49, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(40, 126, 49, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(40, 126, 50, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(41, 127, 50, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(41, 128, 50, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(41, 128, 50, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(41, 129, 51, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(41, 130, 51, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(42, 130, 51, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(42, 131, 52, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(42, 132, 52, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(42, 132, 52, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(42, 133, 52, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(43, 134, 53, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(43, 134, 53, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(43, 135, 53, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(43, 135, 53, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(44, 136, 54, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(44, 137, 54, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(44, 137, 54, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(44, 138, 54, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(44, 138, 54, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(44, 139, 55, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(45, 140, 55, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(45, 140, 55, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(45, 141, 55, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(45, 141, 56, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(45, 142, 56, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(46, 142, 56, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(46, 143, 56, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(46, 143, 56, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(46, 144, 57, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(46, 145, 57, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(46, 145, 57, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(47, 146, 57, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(47, 146, 58, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(47, 147, 58, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(47, 147, 58, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(47, 148, 58, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(47, 148, 58, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(48, 149, 59, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(48, 149, 59, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(48, 150, 59, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(48, 150, 59, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(48, 151, 59, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(48, 151, 60, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(49, 152, 60, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(49, 152, 60, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(49, 153, 60, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(49, 153, 60, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(49, 154, 60, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(49, 154, 61, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(50, 154, 61, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(50, 155, 61, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(50, 155, 61, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(50, 156, 61, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(50, 156, 62, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(50, 157, 62, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(50, 157, 62, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(51, 159, 63, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(51, 159, 63, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(51, 160, 63, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(51, 160, 63, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(52, 161, 63, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(52, 161, 63, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(52, 161, 64, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(52, 162, 64, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(52, 162, 64, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(53, 164, 65, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(53, 164, 65, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(53, 165, 65, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(130, 123, 36, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(131, 124, 37, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(132, 124, 37, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(133, 125, 37, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(133, 126, 37, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(134, 127, 37, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(135, 128, 38, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(136, 128, 38, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(137, 129, 38, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(138, 130, 38, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(138, 131, 39, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(139, 132, 39, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(140, 132, 39, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(141, 133, 39, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(142, 134, 40, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(142, 134, 40, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(143, 135, 40, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(144, 136, 40, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(145, 137, 40, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(145, 137, 41, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(146, 138, 41, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(147, 139, 41, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(148, 139, 41, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(148, 140, 41, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(149, 141, 42, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(150, 141, 42, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(150, 142, 42, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(151, 143, 42, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(152, 143, 42, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(152, 144, 43, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(153, 145, 43, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(154, 145, 43, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(154, 146, 43, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(155, 146, 43, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(156, 147, 44, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(156, 148, 44, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(157, 148, 44, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(158, 149, 44, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(158, 149, 44, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(159, 150, 45, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(160, 151, 45, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(160, 151, 45, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(161, 152, 45, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(161, 152, 45, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(162, 153, 45, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(163, 153, 46, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(163, 154, 46, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(164, 155, 46, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(164, 155, 46, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(165, 156, 46, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(166, 156, 46, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(166, 157, 47, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(167, 157, 47, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(167, 158, 47, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(168, 158, 47, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(168, 159, 47, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(169, 159, 47, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(169, 160, 47, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(170, 160, 48, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(171, 161, 48, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(171, 161, 48, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(172, 162, 48, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(172, 162, 48, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(173, 163, 48, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(173, 163, 49, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(174, 164, 49, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(174, 164, 49, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(175, 165, 49, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(175, 165, 49, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(176, 166, 49, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(176, 166, 49, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(177, 166, 50, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(177, 167, 50, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(178, 167, 50, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(178, 168, 50, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(179, 168, 50, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(179, 169, 50, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(180, 169, 50, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(180, 170, 50, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(180, 170, 51, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(181, 170, 51, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(181, 171, 51, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(182, 171, 51, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(182, 172, 51, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(183, 172, 51, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(183, 173, 51, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(184, 173, 51, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(184, 173, 52, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(184, 174, 52, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(185, 174, 52, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(185, 175, 52, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(186, 175, 52, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(186, 175, 52, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(187, 176, 52, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(187, 176, 52, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(187, 176, 53, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(188, 177, 53, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(188, 177, 53, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(189, 178, 53, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(154, 71, 24, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(155, 72, 24, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(156, 72, 24, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(157, 73, 25, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(158, 73, 25, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(159, 74, 25, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(160, 74, 25, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(161, 75, 25, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(162, 75, 25, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(162, 75, 26, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(163, 76, 26, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(164, 76, 26, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(165, 77, 26, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(166, 77, 26, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(167, 77, 26, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(168, 78, 26, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(169, 78, 27, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(169, 79, 27, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(170, 79, 27, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(171, 79, 27, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(172, 80, 27, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(173, 80, 27, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(173, 81, 27, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(174, 81, 28, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(175, 81, 28, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(176, 82, 28, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(177, 82, 28, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(177, 82, 28, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(178, 83, 28, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(179, 83, 28, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(180, 83, 28, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(180, 84, 29, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(181, 84, 29, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(182, 85, 29, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(182, 85, 29, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(183, 85, 29, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(184, 86, 29, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(185, 86, 29, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(185, 86, 29, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(186, 87, 30, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(187, 87, 30, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(187, 87, 30, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(188, 87, 30, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(189, 88, 30, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(189, 88, 30, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(190, 88, 30, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(191, 89, 30, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(191, 89, 30, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(192, 89, 30, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(193, 90, 31, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(193, 90, 31, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(194, 90, 31, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(194, 90, 31, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(195, 91, 31, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(196, 91, 31, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(196, 91, 31, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(197, 92, 31, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(198, 92, 31, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(198, 92, 32, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(199, 92, 32, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(199, 93, 32, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(200, 93, 32, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(200, 93, 32, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(201, 94, 32, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(202, 94, 32, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(202, 94, 32, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(203, 94, 32, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(203, 95, 32, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(204, 95, 32, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(204, 95, 33, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(205, 95, 33, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(205, 96, 33, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(206, 96, 33, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(206, 96, 33, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(207, 96, 33, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(208, 97, 33, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(208, 97, 33, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(209, 97, 33, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(209, 97, 33, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(210, 98, 33, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(210, 98, 34, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(211, 98, 34, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(211, 98, 34, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(212, 99, 34, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(212, 99, 34, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(213, 99, 34, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(213, 99, 34, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(214, 99, 34, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(214, 100, 34, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(214, 100, 34, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(215, 100, 34, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(215, 100, 34, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(216, 101, 34, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(216, 101, 35, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(217, 101, 35, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(217, 101, 35, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(218, 101, 35, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(218, 102, 35, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(219, 102, 35, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(42, 64, 123, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(43, 65, 124, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(43, 65, 125, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(43, 66, 125, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(43, 66, 126, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(44, 67, 127, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(44, 67, 128, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(44, 67, 129, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(45, 68, 129, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(45, 68, 130, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(45, 69, 131, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(45, 69, 132, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(46, 69, 132, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(46, 70, 133, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(46, 70, 134, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(46, 71, 135, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(47, 71, 135, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(47, 71, 136, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(47, 72, 137, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(47, 72, 138, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(48, 73, 138, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(48, 73, 139, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(48, 73, 140, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(48, 74, 140, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(49, 74, 141, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(49, 74, 142, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(49, 75, 142, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(49, 75, 143, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(50, 75, 144, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(50, 76, 144, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(50, 76, 145, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(50, 76, 146, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(50, 77, 146, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(51, 77, 147, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(51, 77, 147, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(51, 78, 148, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(51, 78, 149, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(52, 78, 149, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(52, 79, 150, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(52, 79, 151, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(52, 79, 151, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(52, 80, 152, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(53, 80, 152, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(53, 80, 153, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(53, 81, 153, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(53, 81, 154, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(53, 81, 155, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(54, 81, 155, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(54, 82, 156, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(54, 82, 156, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(54, 82, 157, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(54, 83, 157, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(55, 83, 158, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(55, 83, 158, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(55, 83, 159, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(55, 84, 159, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(55, 84, 160, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(55, 84, 160, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(56, 85, 161, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(56, 85, 161, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(56, 85, 162, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(56, 85, 162, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(56, 86, 163, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(57, 86, 163, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(57, 86, 164, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(57, 86, 164, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(57, 87, 165, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(57, 87, 165, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(57, 87, 166, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(58, 87, 166, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(58, 88, 167, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(58, 88, 167, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(58, 88, 168, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(58, 88, 168, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(58, 89, 169, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(59, 89, 169, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(59, 90, 171, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(59, 90, 171, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(59, 90, 172, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(60, 90, 172, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(60, 91, 174, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(60, 92, 174, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(60, 92, 175, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(61, 92, 175, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(61, 92, 175, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(61, 92, 176, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(61, 93, 176, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(62, 93, 178, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(62, 94, 178, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(62, 94, 179, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: #141414;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card__back span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 30px;
}

</style>

<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();


  
</script>

<script>
<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
  const currentCard = $(this); 

  hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
    currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
    var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
    currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

    // Add fullscreen functionality
    currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
      $(this).requestFullscreen();
    });

    // Handle video ending
    currentCard.find('.iframe').on('ended', function() {
    currentCard.find('.card__front').show();
    currentCard.find('.iframe').remove();
});
    
  }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)

}, function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); 

  $(this).find('.card__front').show();
  $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
  var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
  $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
});


</script>

<script>
//sound effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");

  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);

    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

  
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
        flipSound.currentTime = 0; 
        flipSound.play();
      }

      card.toggleClass("flipped");

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); 
    }
  });

 
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});


</script>


</html>
```

Hello friends, sometimes when I turn the cards from front to back, there is no sound. How can I fix this? audio file is 1 sec long. it occurs especially when you do it fast.

In short, I can't get the sound to be heard every time I rotate the cards from front to back.

Note: It takes a short time for the cards to turn to the back side, but I set the turn time to be 1 second. I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

The sound file:
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iOqH232jf-UCOi4jcd8auOXklyUxmom5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your toggleClass() to a removeClass()

```js
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();


<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
  const currentCard = $(this); // Store the current card element in a variable

  hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
    currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
    var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
    currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

    // Add fullscreen functionality
    currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
      $(this).requestFullscreen();
    });

    // Handle video ending
    currentCard.find('.iframe').on('ended', function() {
    currentCard.find('.card__front').show();
    currentCard.find('.iframe').remove();
});
    
  }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)

}, function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

  $(this).find('.card__front').show();
  $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
  var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
  $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
});

//sound effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");

  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);

    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
        flipSound.currentTime = 0; // Reset the audio to the start
        flipSound.play();
      }

      card.removeClass("flipped");

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); // Adjust the timeout to match your animation duration
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(48, 48, 48, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  animation: shine 2s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}

.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: #141414;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card__back span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 

<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://sndup.net/p3fj/d" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<main>
  <h1>TM</h1>
  <p>Game Cards.</p>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>
<ul>
  <li class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvels</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
  <iframe class="frame" 
  width="225"
  height="340"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
  title="YouTube video player"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
  allowfullscreen
></iframe>

      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>113.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <p class="card__name"><span>Aaron</span><br>Rodgers</p>
        <p class="card__num">12</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>112.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Ben</span><br>Roethlisberger</p>
        <p class="card__num">7</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>103.3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Peyton</span><br>Manning</p>
        <p class="card__num">18</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>101.5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Tom</span><br>Brady</p>
        <p class="card__num">Eric</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Drew</span><br>Brees</p>
        <p class="card__num">9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```